# How to measure Image's offset after it was clipped with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As I said above, I have a picture, and I use contentScale parameter set to Fit. Then I want to read its offsets, so lately I can use it to draw some content on it using canvas. But those offsets will be always maxed out, since I use fillMaxSize() modifier, without it it won't fit the photo to borders of the parent as it supposed to. How do I fix this, so I can have it fitted in parent box bounds and have measured offsets?

```
AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(src)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rip),
        error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rip),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.DarkGray) // to see that it covers whole available space
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                size = it.size
                imageOffsetStart.value = it.boundsInRoot().topLeft
                imageOffsetEnd.value = it.boundsInRoot().bottomRight
            }
)
```

Example:

[image]

I tried to get rid of fillMaxSize() but I don't know how to make it fit the parent box (whole screen in this example) due to longer width/height of an image.

Comment: I built a library that returns draw area as rectangle to draw on only the bounds image was drawn. You can check it [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Image) The implementation depends on `contentScale.computeScaleFactor(srcSize, dstSize)` where srcSize is Bitmap in pixel and dstSize is size of Composable, Image for instance, and further calculations are required to get rectangle.

Comment: @Thracian your code and particularly your Compose Guides app helped me a lot. Thank you. I managed to solve this with creating a ImageBitmap from file path, it has width/height, it helped me scale the picture inside of the Box composable.

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that it helped. You can post your solution as answer to help others out

Comment: Do you mean Compose tutorial by Compose Guides app?

Comment: @Thracian Yes, this https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials was very useful. I'll share the code in my post later this evening.